# Задание min-width флекс элемента на основании min-width содержимого

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css3, flexbox

Всем привет. Вопрос следующий. Имеется флекс-контейнер, допустим ограниченный 800 px. Имеется динамическое количество флекс-элементов, состоящих из label и span, содержимое которых также является динамическим. Мне необходимо, если табы полностью не помещаются в контейнер начинать сокращать label во флекс-элементах. При этом ширина не должна стать меньше 3 символов + многоточия (это приблизительно достигается за счет min-width: 6ch). На данный момент если у какого-то таба очень длинное название, начинают уменьшаться другие табы, что вызывает переполнение флекс-элемента и span обрезается. При этом другие табы еще не достигли своего минимального значения (min-width лейбла + gap + span). Захардкодить min-width таба само собой не вариант - контент динамический (span может содержать разные числа). Различные значения min-width таба (min-content, fit-content) вообще не дают тексту обрезаться.
Прилагаю изображения, демонстрирующие проблему, ссылку на CodeSandbox и примерный код.
Буду благодарен за любую помощь.
[Ссылка на codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-dijkstra-61s9sp?file=/src/Component.jsx:0-1606)

Табам хватает места (все хорошо)
[image: Табам хватает места (все хорошо)]

Длинное название у таба - начинают вылезать span у других табов (хотя min-width лейбла не достигнут)
[image: Длинное название у таба - начинают вылезать span у других табов (хотя min-width лейбла не достигнут)]

Ожидаемое поведение (тут хардкод min-width табов (само собой такое решение не подходит))
[image: Ожидаемое поведение (тут хардкод min-width табов (само собой такое решение не подходит))]

```js
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

const TabsList = styled.ul`
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  background: yellowgreen;
  /* because the first tab always will be "all" */
  li:first-of-type label {
    min-width: 20px;
  }
`;

const singleNumPaddingStyles = "0 8px";

const KeywordTab = styled.li`
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  gap: 8px;
  label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 23px;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    &:hover {
      color: blue;
    }
    /* trying to set minimum 3char + ... */
    min-width: 6ch;
  }

  span {
    color: white;
    line-height: 23px;
    background-color: pink;
    user-select: none;
    padding: ${({ singleNum }) =>
      singleNum ? singleNumPaddingStyles : "0 4px"};
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
`;

const Group = ({ label, number }) => (
  <KeywordTab singleNum={number < 10}>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <span>{number}</span>
  </KeywordTab>
);

export const View = ({ dictionaries }) => {
  //logic (useLayoutEffect)
  return (
    <TabsList>
      {dictionaries.map(({ label, total }, index) => (
        <Group key={index} label={label} number={total} />
      ))}
    </TabsList>
  );
};
```

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  color: #454545;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0%);
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font: 300 18px/26px "Yantramanav", "Helvetica", "Noto", serif;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добился предполагаемого поведения перейдя от flexbox к grid.На родительском контейнере стал динамически задавать количество столбцов (кроме первого, ибо по логике предполагалось, что там постоянно элемент - all),а ширину определять выражением minmax(min-content, max-content). В отдельном элементе сделал grid из двух столбцов, где 1-ый - 1fr, 2-ой - min-content.

```js
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import { useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState, forwardRef } from "react";


export const TabsListGrid = styled.ul`
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  list-style: none;
  background: yellowgreen;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: min-content repeat(${({ columns }) => columns - 1}, minmax(min-content, max-content));
  max-width: 712px;
  li:first-of-type label {
    min-width: min-content;
  }
`

const singleNumPaddingStyles = "0 8px";

const KeywordTab = styled.li`
  flex-shrink: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr min-content;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  label {
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 23px;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    &:hover {
      color: blue;
    }
    min-width: 6ch;
  }

  span {
    color: white;
    line-height: 23px;
    background-color: pink;
    user-select: none;
    padding: ${({ singleNum }) =>
      singleNum ? singleNumPaddingStyles : "0 4px"};
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
`;

const Group = forwardRef(({ label, number }, ref) => (
  <KeywordTab ref={ref} singleNum={number < 10}>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <span>{number}</span>
  </KeywordTab>
));

export const View = ({ dictionaries }) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  const tabsRef = useRef(null);
  const tabRef = useRef([]);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (tabsRef?.current?.getBoundingClientRect().width < 500) {
      setVisible(false);
    } else {
      setVisible(true);
    }
    console.log(tabRef);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      {visible && (
        <TabsListGrid ref={tabsRef} columns={dictionaries.length}>
          {dictionaries.map(({ label, total }, index) => (
            <Group
              ref={(el) => (tabRef.current[index] = el)}
              key={index}
              label={label}
              number={total}
            />
          ))}
        </TabsListGrid>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```